# can't access message in header function in php

Tags: php

Hi I'm just trying to show incorrect username & password on the login page everything works out good except showing "incorrect username & password" showing on the same page using header function. Can anyone help? below is my php code.

```
<?php
include 'db.php';

$user = $_POST['user'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE username='$user' AND password='$pass'";

$result = $con->query($sql);
if(!$row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    echo "The User Name or Password you entered is incorrect!";

}else{

    header("Location: home.html");
} 
?>
```

I want to show "The User Name or Password you entered is incorrect!" message along with header file as variable and I don't understand how to access variable in header file. Suggestions?

Comment: Maybe you should read up on Bobby Tables beforehand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to redirect php file to use variables in header function.
example, you pass id and a number values $var1 and $var2 respectively

```
header('location: index.php?id='.$var1. '&num=' .$var2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
include 'db.php';
session_start();
$user = $_POST['user'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE username='$user' AND password='$pass'";

$result = $con->query($sql);
if(!$row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    $_SESSION['error_message'] =  "The User Name or Password you entered is incorrect!";
 header(//////your page///////);

}else{

    header("Location: home.html");
}
```

**Your page.php**

```
echo $_SESSION['error_message'];
```

Comment: Guys Thanks for your quick responses but I don't see any of them working because I just see variable displayed only on the address bar itself not showing on page.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 if(!$row = $result->fetch_assoc())
 {
    header("Location: home.html?error='The User Name or Password you entered is incorrect!'");
 }else{
    header("Location: home.html");
 }
```

You also have to rename the `home.html` file to `home.php` and in the `home.php` you can check if there is any errors and show them like that:

```
<?php 
if($_GET('error')) {
   echo htmlspecialchars($_GET('error'));
}
?>
```